# Is HttpContext.Current.Items thread-safe between Requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Suppose one has an HttpHandler that processes each request, and suppose each HttpHandler computes an intermediate result for each request and potentially wants to pass this to a page handler eg via Server.Transfer or Server.Execute via the HttpContext.Items collection

Will each request have a separate copy of HttpContext.Items["sameKey"] when they each reach the same .aspx page?

My concern arises from the fact HttpContext.Current is itself a static property

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **HttpContext** Encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP
>   request.

Hence each request HttpContext.Items["sameKey"] will be a different copy.

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Items is stateless the only way to "share" between requests is Session or higher level state (database)

Comment: In this case, technically isn't this the same request still, from the browser's point of view? Because this is Server.Transfer, not Response.Redirect ...so technically isn't it still the same HTTP request?

Comment: It doesnt matter, each Server.transfer will have different Items; although it's static, it relies on a Thread Context (each request keeps its Items in its own Thread context)