# HttpContext.Current.Items after an Async operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, async-await

Consider the following ASP.NET Web API Delegating Handler:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        HttpContext.Current.Items["foo"] = guid;

        // An Async operation
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        //All code from this point is not gauranteed to run on the same thread that started the handler

        var restoredGuid = (Guid)HttpContext.Current.Items["foo"];

        //Is this gauranteed to be true
        var areTheSame = guid == restoredGuid;

        return result;
    }
}
```

The above example is in a delegating handler, the same problem I am trying to fix applies in Controllers, Business Objects, etc.

I am ultimately trying to provide some simple in-memory shared state between various objects per HTTP Request

As I understand it during Async operations the ASP.NET thread originally running the operation is returned to the thread pool and a different thread may be used to finish the request after the Async operation has completed.

Does this affect the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection?
Is an item that was in the `Items` collection guaranteed to be there when the Request resumes?

1. I'm aware that using `HttpContext.Current` is often frowned upon by
   the wider community these days for reasons I completely agree
   with... I'm just helping someone out of a jam.
2. Storing this data in the `Request.Items` collection is not suitable to solve this problem as my colleague requires a static due to some poor design decisions.

Many Thanks

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261571/is-httpcontext-current-items-thread-safe-between-requests

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196556/httpcontext-current-items-in-different-thread

Comment: Hi Jason, those questions; whilst similar; are not quite the same thing. Thanks though.

Comment: Ahh OK :) No worries.

Comment: `HttpContext` will be preserved, but the continuation thread might not be the same . [AspNetSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) will manage the context.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> As I understand it during Async operations the ASP.NET thread originally running the operation is returned to the thread pool and a different thread may be used to finish the request after the Async operation has completed.

That is correct. But let's talk about `async` on ASP.NET for just a minute.

`async` requires .NET 4.5. Furthermore, ASP.NET 4.5 introduces a "quirks mode" on the server side, and you have to turn the `SynchronizationContext` quirk *off*. You can do this by either setting `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to `4.5` *or* using an `appSettings` with `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` value of `true`.

If your web.config does not have one of those entries, then the behavior of `async` is undefined. See [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) for more details. I recommend using the `targetFramework` setting and fixing any problems that come up.

> Does this affect the HttpContext.Current.Items collection? Is an item that was in the Items collection guaranteed to be there when the Request resumes?

The `AspNetSynchronizationContext` preserves the current request context across `await` points. This includes `HttpContext.Current` (which includes `Items`, `User`, etc).

Another possibility is `CallContext.Logical[Get|Set]Data`, which also flows across `await` points. This is useful if you don't want a code dependency on `HttpContext`, but has slightly more overhead.

I gave a talk at ThatConference a couple weeks ago on [`async` on the server side](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/slides-available-thatconference-2013.html); you may find the slides helpful, particularly the ones dealing with Context and Thread-Local State.

Answer (score 6):

Cutting a long story short, it normally should. Unless you are using `ConfigureAwait(false)` which can have a side effect with continuation not flowing the context.

Alternatively try adding this setting in your app.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

### UPDATE

NOTE!!
Initially I put false. But it must be **true** so that context flows.